# Add multiple identical elements to array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How would I add multiple identical elements to an array?

For instance, if the array was:

```
["Swan", "Dog"]
```

and I wanted to turn it into:

```
["Swan", "Dog", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat"]
```

(adding 10 `Cat`s)

It there a simple command I can do, which does not use a loop?

Answer (score 26):

In **Swift 3** you can use `repeatElement()` which creates a collection containing the specified number of the given element:

```
var array = ["Swan", "Dog"]
array.append(contentsOf: repeatElement("Cat", count: 10))
```

In **Swift 2** this would be:

```
var array = ["Swan", "Dog"]
array.appendContentsOf(Repeat(count: 10, repeatedValue: "cat"))
```

Answer (score 7):

The array initilizer `Array(repeating:count:)` can be used to create an array with repeated values:

```
var myArray = ["Swan", "Dog"]
myArray += Array(repeating: "Cat", count: 10)
```